# TortoiseSVN update svn:property on the same file every time a commit happens

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, propertyinfo

I'm developing C# on Visual Studio. I was able to config TortouseSVN to use $Rev$ property inside the main .cs file. As I tested, every time this .cs file is changed, latest revision number is updated on this file.

But then new tests showed that if any other file is changed and commited, this .cs file doesn't have latest revision number.

I'm thinking then on using Visual Studio's standard `\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file to store SVN's $Rev$ property, and use .Net assembly to read it as I already do with FileVersion. This also has the advantage of storing version/revision metadata separated from normal source code.

But then, is there a way to setup Subversion/TortoiseSVN to always update $Rev$ property on a given file it is present, even when this file hasn't changed?

**Update.** What I'm looking to achieve is to automatically store the last revision the SVN folder was commited. This number will then be part of compiled binary (which will be generated after commit) and be shown in logs together with the app version, and be used on DEV, TQS and PRD environments. This way I'll keep in each log what revision a given execution refered to and be able to see what had changed since that execution and current HEAD.

Of course this is an app-wide info and not a specific info per source file. But I think SVN won't support updating a specific file every time a commit happens.

My best idea, a very very ugly one, would be to create a static class and during startup make each object, as they are instantiated, call it and inform their revision. This class method would then store the max value, which would then be app's compiled revision.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to solve the issue you're having, but I can explain *why* you're seeing what you're seeing. Whenever you're making a change to `main.cs`, **it's** latest revision is the last revision it was changed. Doesn't matter how many other files you've changed since commit 100, if commit 100 was the last time you changed that particular file. The only way you would be able to get this to work consistently, as far as I see at least, is to make a change to a particular file (in this case, main.cs) every single time you make a commit. But that would be tedious and nonsensical.

Comment: I guess a better question is, what are you trying to accomplish by updating a particular file with the revision number? Maybe there's a more convenient way to handle whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Chris, that's what I was guessing too. $Rev$ refers to the last revision a given file was changed. I'm updating the question.